# Unable to connect to Redis in GCP which is SSL Enabled

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, redis, spring-data-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am using `Spring-boot-starter-redis` dependency to connect to redis (below is my snippet from gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```

I am moving to GCP now and the redis in GCP is SSL Enabled and so, i configured my spring properties this way

```
spring.redis.ssl=true
spring.redis.host=xxxxxx
spring.redis.port=6378
```

It works perfectly fine when i disable the ssl. But when i enable it, i get below error.. is there any way to inject the PEM ceritificate in Spring configuration ?

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:6378] with root cause
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1334) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1231) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008) ~[na:na]
```

please help

Comment: I think the issue is that your client is validating the SSL certificate for Redis and that is failing. Your question is not clear if you are using self-hosted Redis, Cloud MemoryStore, or Redis Enterprise.

Comment: Am using Cloud Memory Store

Comment: Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/in-transit-encryption

Comment: I recommend changing one of your tags to **google-cloud-memorystore**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tackled it this way

- `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` dependency uses Lettuce by default
- To connect to Redis through ssl `spring.redis.ssl=true` property need to be enabled.
- If the CA of the ceritificate is unique and not part of Java's JKS, then you have two options, either import the keys to JKS or disable the `SSL-Verification`

Quoting whats given in [Google Docs here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/enabling-in-transit-encryption#installing_a_certificate_authority_on_your_client)

> For example, Lettuce is a popular Java client for Redis. Their documentation provides an example for connecting natively with TLS (see Example 47). Given that the Java Security Manager does not allow self-signed certificates by default, an additional option needs to be specified in the Redis URI construction `.withVerifyPeer(false)`

I disabled the `SSL Verification` . The connection will still happen through SSL, but the verification alone i disabled it by configuring a bean.

Also am not worried about `man-in-the-middle-attack` as my Redis is exposed only to my GKE Cluster.. So this solution worked fine for me

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisSSLConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("spring.redis.ssl")
    public LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer builderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.useSsl().disablePeerVerification();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced same Issue. After doing so much analysis finally I found the proper way to connect to GCP Memorystore Redis Server with SSL Enabled from my java client.

Following the Code Snippet and Steps.

Step 1 : Download server-ca.pem(Or any Server CA) file from GCP -> Console -> MemoryStore -> Redis -> Security Tab -> download server-ca.pem.

Step 2 : move the downloaded file into java client(your java application) class path.

```
@Configuration 
public class CacheConfig {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() throws IOException {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("ipaddress_of_gcpmemorystore_redis");
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword("auth_string_from_security_tab");
    SslOptions sslOptions = SslOptions.builder().
            trustManager(resourceLoader.getResource("file:/home/<user_name>/server-ca.pem").getFile()).build();
    ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder().sslOptions(sslOptions).protocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.RESP3).build();
    LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .clientOptions(clientOptions).useSsl().build();
    LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory =  new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration,
            lettuceClientConfiguration);
    return connectionFactory;
}
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() throws IOException {
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}}
```