# Unable to connect to GCP Redis with SSL enabled. Is there any way to pass .Pem Certifcate in spring configs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, ssl-certificate, pem, spring-data-redis

**currently this is how I am connecting with redis..If someone can let me know how to configure ssl options to use .pem certificate will be very useful**

```
  @Bean
  LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    final SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder()
      .keepAlive(true).build();
    final ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
      .socketOptions(socketOptions).build();
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = redisUtil.isSslEnable()? LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
      .clientOptions(clientOptions).useSsl().build():LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
      .clientOptions(clientOptions).build();
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisUtil.getHost(),
      redisUtil.getPort());
    serverConfig.setPassword(redisUtil.getKey());
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig, clientConfig);
  }
```

Comment: Does this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835726/unable-to-connect-to-redis-in-gcp-which-is-ssl-enabled) help you?

Answer (score 0):

As shared above by [Mousumi Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17069758/mousumi-roy), there are two possible options:

1. Download [server-ca.pem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72760710/16313960) from your Cloud Memorystore for Redis, and configure it in your code.
2. Disable [SSL Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843387/16313960), something you may not want to do.

HTH