# Cannot connect to redis server with TLS from .NET Core

Tags: .net, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

**What I am doing**

I have two Google Cloud instances.

- A Cloud Run Service (.NET Core Web API Server)
- Memorystore for Redis (TLS enabled)

I would like to connect to Memorystore Redis server from my .NET app running on Cloud Run.

**My Code**

I downloaded `server-ca.pem` from Google Cloud console, and I followed [this sample code](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_csharp/#tls).

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var redisOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints = {{"xx.xx.xx.xx", 6378}},
    Ssl = true,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
};

redisOptions.CertificateSelection += delegate
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2("server-ca.pem", "");
    return cert;
};

var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisOptions);
```

But below error occurs.

> Unhandled exception. StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It
> was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). There was an
> authentication failure; check that passwords (or client certificates)
> are configured correctly: (AuthenticationException) The remote
> certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain:
> PartialChain

If I use this code,

```
var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("server-ca.pem");
```

different error occurs.

> Unhandled exception.
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key contents
> do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not
> match the certificate.

How can I connect to redis server from .NET app with TLS encryption?

Comment: Download server-ca.pem from your Cloud Memorystore for Redis, and configure it in your code.check step1 on downloading server-ca.pem in this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72760710/18265638)  if you downloaded correct server-ca.pem file